# Looking to Identify a pin/ badge

Tags: identification, united-kingdom, 1950s

[image]

I am looking to identify this badge that my grandfather was wearing in this picture I know it’s blurry but never seen it before and don’t know where to start looking for a way to identify it.

He would have been about 24/25 at the time of the photo. He was from London and he worked for a pharmaceutical company. We think the photo was taken in the late 1950s around 1957-1958. He did Service in the British army, and he was artistic. That’s about as much as we know.

Comment: This is will probably be hard. When was the photo taken? How old would your grandfather have been at that time?

Comment: Maybe a Fire Service commemorative pin? It could show a helmet with crossed axes behind it. (An orginal officer's badge would probably be much larger.)

Comment: Context is what will help you (and us) narrow this down. What do you know about your grandpa: Where did he live? What did he do? Who did he work for? Did he have any political affiliations? What is his educational background? Military service? Any known club/fraternal organization memberships?  This is the type of information which can help narrow down an identification of an item like this. Anything you know and can share may help.

Comment: Hi yeah sorry he would have been about 24/25 at the time of the photo he was from London and he worked for a pharmaceutical company . We think the photo was taken in the late 1950s around 1957 1958  he did Service in the British army and he was artistic that’s about as much as we know

Comment: @Tash, please update the **question** with everything you know; everything that could be useful for research.  Juscal has added your comment; if you think justcal's edit is correct, please flag the relevant comments for deletion.